# Laravel crear una regla que dependa de otra

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, validación

Ya que estoy usando [un manejador de archivos](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager-example-5.3)  el resquest que recibo es una url y para validarla cree 2 reglas, la primera comprueba si es una imagen y la segunda si tiene el mismo largo que ancho, como puedo hacer para que la segunda al fallar el try retorne la primera o que compruebe primero la primera para ejecutar la segunda, para que no tenga que colocar las reglas siempre en orden 'imagen' => 'required|imagenurl|imagenurlradioigual', también quiero saber si hay una mejor forma de validar la imagen

```
Validator::extend('imagenurl', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        try {
            return getimagesize(env('APP_URL').$value);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    Validator::extend('imagenurlradioigual', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        try {
            $imagen = getimagesize(env('APP_URL').$value);
            return $imagen[0] == $imagen[1];
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Prueba usando `bail` al inicio de tus reglas (```'image' => 'bail|required|image…'```): https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-bail.

Comment: Te serviría usar Intervention Image http://image.intervention.io/ ?